# No table is being created neither the RestController Url is working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

please tell what I am doing wrong, the code is running with no errors but I am getting no tables or the working restcontroller url whatsoever

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.usere.entity.UserEntity;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usr")
public class Ucontroller {


@RequestMapping("/showall")
public UserEntity showall()
{
    return new UserEntity("abc",29);
}
}
```

pojo or model for rest

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usrtbl")
public class UserEntity {


@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int uid;


@Column(name = "name")
private String usrname;

@Column(name = "age")
private int age;

public UserEntity(String string, int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    usrname=string;
    age=i;
}

//getter setters omitted
}
```

the autogenerated class
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class UserEnittyApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(UserEnittyApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

servlet initializer(auto generated)
    public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
application) {
    return application.sources(UserEnittyApplication.class);
}

}
```

Pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.user</groupId>
<artifactId>UserEnitty</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>UserEnitty</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

----------------------------EOF------------------

application.properties

```
server.port=7777

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poncho
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver




spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =         
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true


spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/view/    // I tried using a simple controller 
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp      // it didn't work too.
```

console

````
2019-08-25 10:41:06.534  INFO 9608 --- [           main] com.usere.demo.UserEnittyApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-25 10:41:08.997  INFO 9608 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-08-25 10:41:09.055  INFO 9608 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 37ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-08-25 10:41:09.925  INFO 9608 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d899bdb3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-25 10:41:10.761  INFO 9608 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 7777 (http)
2019-08-25 10:41:10.840  INFO 9608 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-25 10:41:10.841  INFO 9608 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-08-25 10:41:11.205  INFO 9608 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-25 10:41:11.206  INFO 9608 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4551 ms
2019-08-25 10:41:11.653  INFO 9608 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-08-25 10:41:12.147  INFO 9608 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-08-25 10:41:12.328  INFO 9608 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-08-25 10:41:12.533  INFO 9608 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-08-25 10:41:12.537  INFO 9608 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-08-25 10:41:12.938  INFO 9608 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-08-25 10:41:13.309  INFO 9608 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-08-25 10:41:13.874  INFO 9608 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-08-25 10:41:14.769  INFO 9608 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-25 10:41:14.954  WARN 9608 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-08-25 10:41:15.610  INFO 9608 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 7777 (http) with context path ''
2019-08-25 10:41:15.618  INFO 9608 --- [           main] com.usere.demo.UserEnittyApplication     : Started UserEnittyApplication in 9.922 seconds (JVM running for 13.859)```
````

Comment: Your Service or Repository class, where do you call it in your Controller?

Comment: Do I really need them, I tried it yesterday with making an interface which extends the JpaRepository class but it didn't work at all, I am just returning a dummy object to see if something gets returned as a json.

Comment: Read my answer. I think the problem is that you don’t write to your db

Comment: please add your project structure(your packages and classes)

Answer (score 1):

Create a repository class and call it for example `UserEntityRepository` like this:

```
public interface UserEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {
}
```

Now create a service class and call it `UserEntityService` like this:

```
public interface PlayerService {

    List<UserEntity> findAll();

    Player findById(int theId);

    void save(UserEntity theUserEntity);

    void deleteById(int theId);    
}
```

You don't necessarily need all these methods but these are common used crud methods.

Then you need to create a class that implements your service class for example:

```
@Service
public class UserEntityServiceImpl implements UserEntityService {

    private UserEntityRepository userEntityRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CompanyBlueprintServiceImpl(UserEntityRepository theUserEntityRepository ) {
        userEntityRepository= theUserEntityRepository ;
    }

...
    @Override
    public void save(UserEntity theUserEntity) {
        userEntityRepository.save(theUserEntity);
    }
}
```

After doing all this you have to use your `UserEntityService` in your controller class. So you can call the `save()` method from your service to save your entity in your db.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Ucontroller {

private UserEntityService userEntityService;

public Ucontroller(UserEntityService theUserEntityService) {
userEntityService = theUserEntityService;
}

@RequestMapping("/showall")
public UserEntity showall()
{
    return new UserEntity("abc",29);
}

@PostMapping("/users")
    public UserEntity addUser(@RequestBody UserEntity theUserEntity) {

        // just in case an id in JSON was pass ... set id to 0
        // this is to force a save of new item ... instead of update
        theUserEntity.setUid(0);

        userEntityService.save(theUserEntity);

        return theCompany;
    }

}
```

What you did is just creating a `UserEntity` object and returning it in your controller method `showAll()`.
After saving the userEntity you should see the row in your db.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to bother but I did a great mistake, the project package wasn't named correctly[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWRgP.png)

you see the default generated package is com.usere.demo, earlier I named the other packages as com.usere.controller/entity which was wrong and we shouldn't do that, I thought it might not be important to post the package name, that said the correct name should be com.usere.demo.[anything you desire], thank you Constantin Beer and BaDr Amer for helping instantly and telling the right convention and workflow but it was a very stupid mistake that I made.